# How to determine if a Post contains a specific Category in a JSONP feed using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jsonp

I need to detect if a post contains a specific category from a JSONP feed. I'm not sure how to read the array as it's currently saying it's null. The link works without any problems though, which is just a string.

```
$.jsonp({
    url         : "theurl",
    dataType    : "jsonp",
    timeout     : 10000,
    success     : myFunction,
    error       : myErrorFunction
});

function myFunction (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, post){
        var link = post.permalink,
            hasCategory = $.inArray("specialcategory", post.categories);
    });
}
```

Here's an example of my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "permalink": "http://domain.com",
        "categories": [
            "category1",
            "specialcategory"
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the error that appears in Firebug:

```
can't convert null to object
d()jquery.js (line 16)
a = "specialcategory"
b = undefined
[Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function ci(a){return d...a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=d})(window);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about an example of the JSON?

Comment: How exactly is the browser "saying it's null"?  I don't see any null check in the code you posted.  That all looks fine.

Comment: What does post.toString() yield?

Comment: I've posted the error that shows up in Firebug above.

Comment: @Peder Rice: It returns "[object Object]" in Firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to check for `hasCategory` differently - see the jQuery docs:

> The `$.inArray()` method is similar to JavaScript's native `.indexOf()` method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, `$.inArray()` returns 0.
>
> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of `value` within `array`, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.

So the line

```
hasCategory = $.inArray("specialcategory", post.categories);
```

should be

```
hasCategory = $.inArray("specialcategory", post.categories) >= 0;
```

But it doesn't look like that's your main issue, if `myFunction` isn't actually receiving the array of data.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. :(